# Cohomology ring of Klein bottle over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: solution-verification, homology-cohomology

I was trying to compute cohomology ring of Klein bottle, K, over $\mathbb{Z}$, and I just wanted to confirm what the answer was.
I had found it to be $$H^*(K, \mathbb{Z}) = \frac{\mathbb{Z} [x, y]}{\langle x^2, y^2, xy ,2y \rangle}$$ where $x$ is of degree $1$, and $y$ is of degree $2$.

Is this calculation right? Or is there some mistake somewhere?  I wasn't able to confirm it anywhere I checked.

Comment: This looks good to me ^_^.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks! :)